# Use const to calculate other const expressions with casting

Tags: rust

Currently I have the following

```
const WIDTH : u16 = 1920;
const HEIGHT: u16 = 1080;
const PIXELS : usize = 1920 * 1080;
```

It would be nicer to have something like

```
const WIDTH : u16 = 1920;
const HEIGHT: u16 = 1080;
const PIXELS : usize = usize::from(WIDTH) * usize::from(HEIGHT);
```

But this will not compile. I assume this is because `const` are compile time variables and can't rely on the execution of `usize::from`. Is there an alternative?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`usize::from` is not a constant function. If it were, your example would compile just fine. Instead, you can use simply cast the variables, which is all `usize::from` does internally:

```rust
const WIDTH : u16 = 1920;
const HEIGHT: u16 = 1080;
const PIXELS: usize = (WIDTH as usize) * (HEIGHT as usize);
```